# xpath attribute subtract or remove /deselect

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I remove xpath attribute. I want to remove/deselect all object with
a style of `display: none` attribute.

xpath I used:

```
//div[contains(@class,'x-column-header grid-header-ellipses-cls x-column-header') and contains(@style,'auto')]
```

There are over 50 elements with this same xpath, but I am required to eliminated object with `display: none;`. There will be about 10 such objects. How can I handle such object.

HTML code:

```
style="border-width: 1px; width: 60px; right: auto; left: 433px; margin: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;"
```

Please share your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another AND operator and use NOT to remove those results:

```
//div[contains(@class,'x-column-header grid-header-ellipses-cls x-column-header') and contains(@style,'auto') and not(contains(@style, 'display: none')]
```